# Py4JJavaError Inner Join on Large Dataset

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, databricks

When writing a large dataset file as a parquet to S3 with an inner join I receive a Py4JJavaError.

When I write `training_data` to the S3 path theres no issue. However, filtering/inner joining the dataset with `psu_data` and then writing `filtered_train_data` to the S3 path results in the error.[Py4JJavaError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FScYU.png)

I was expecting the initial dataset to be inner joined with the `psu_data` dataset and be written to the S3 path as a parquet file.